# Returning numbers equal to or less than 6 in a Python list within a for

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to return within this FOR only values equal to or less than 6 in each column.

```
colunas = list(df2.columns[8:19])
colunas

['Satisfação geral',
 'Comunicação',
 'Expertise da industria',
 'Inovação',
 'Parceira',
 'Proatividade',
 'Qualidade',
 'responsividade',
 'Pessoas',
 'Expertise técnico',
 'Pontualidade']

lista = []

for coluna in colunas:
   nome_coluna = coluna
   #total_parcial = df2[coluna].count()
   df2.loc[df2[coluna]<=6].shape[0]
   percentual = df2[coluna].count() / df2[coluna].count()
   lista.append([nome_coluna,total_parcial,percentual])

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=lista, columns=['nome_coluna','total_parcial','percentual'])
```

But returns the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-364994f742fd> in <module>()
      4    nome_coluna = coluna
      5    #total_parcial = df2[coluna].count()
----> 6    df2.loc[df2[coluna]<=6].shape[0]
      7    percentual = df2[coluna].count() / df2[coluna].count()
      8    lista.append([nome_coluna,total_parcial,percentual])

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
     54         result = libops.vec_compare(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
     55     else:
---> 56         result = libops.scalar_compare(x.ravel(), y, op)
     57     return result.reshape(x.shape)
     58 

pandas/_libs/ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare()

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

If I put the code that is giving the error alone in a line it works

```
df2.loc[df2['Pontualidade'] <= 6].shape[0]

1537
```

What is the correct syntax?
Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Do you just want the list of values in each column that are <= 6?  Do you want the whole row?  You seem to be trying to compute a percentage, but incorrectly.  Please be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your DataFrame's columns contains strings, rather than numbers. If every column is supposed to be numeric, you can cast the rows to numbers by adding `.astype(float)` to the left side of the comparison, ie,

```
df2.loc[df2[coluna].astype(float)<=6].shape[0]
# Will return the number of rows with values less than or equal to 6
```

You could also use `.astype(int)` if they should be integers. Note that either will still raise an error if your column contains values that can't be cast to numbers. And regardless, it is probably better to find out why a column you expect to be numeric isn't earlier in your code.

As an aside, as the comparison will return as series of booleans, you can simplify and clarify the code by simply taking a sum of the booleans, ie

```
(df2[coluna].astype(float)<=6).sum()
# Will also return the number of rows with values less than or equal to 6
```

Comment: Thanks.
I just changed from float to int in your code, as instructed above, and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One or some of your columns has non-numeric values.
If you are sure the columns all should be numeric, use
`df2[column_name] = pandas.to_numeric(df2[column_name])`

to make sure that no number strings, like "123", are mixed in there.

Answer (score 0):

First, your syntax there is correct. The error is related to types. It seems that some of your columns have strings instead of numbers in them, which would cause this error when comparing to a number. You can check the type of the columns with `df2.dtypes`.

Comment: Thanks.
His explanation was important to my understanding of how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one of the columns you test contains strings instead of numbers?
That would explain the thrown error.
A good debugging-step would be to print the column-name at the beginning of the loop to see in which iteration it fails.